# Ejecutar dos cmd desde otro cmd y guardar la salida en dos txt

Tags: cmd

tengo un problema a la hora de ejecutar dos programas cmd y registrar la salida en este ejecutarProgramas.cmd:

```
CD C:\Users\usuario\Documents
ECHO LLAMADA A PROGRAMA A
ProgramaA.cmd > ProgramaA.txt
ECHO LLAMADA A PROGRAMA B
ProgramaB.cmd > ProgramaB.txt
pause
exit
```

Al abrir una consola de windows "cmd" me situo en la carpeta que contiene ejecutarProgramas.cmd (Escritorio) y si ejecuto "ejecutarProgramas.cmd" ejecuta correctamente el CD, el ECHO y el ProgramaA.cmd, pero se queda en la línea de comandos sin hacer nada después:

```
C:\Users\usuario\Desktop>"ejecutarProgramas.cmd"

C:\Users\usuario\Desktop>CD C:\Users\usuario\Documents

C:\Users\usuario\Documents>ECHO LLAMADA A PROGRAMA A
LLAMADA A PROGRAMA A

C:\Users\usuario\Documents>"ProgramaA.cmd"1>ProgramaA.txt

C:\Users\usuario\Documents>
```

¿Por qué no continúa la ejecución? Me mosquea ese 1 que hay antes del >. He probado poniendo comillas a ProgramaA.cmd y ProgramaB.cmd y funciona igual. Si antepongo el comando START a la llamada se abre en otra ventana pero no guarda la salida en el txt sino que lo muestra por la consola de esa nueva ventana.

He intentado buscar la solución en esta página pero no la encuentro, y en la versión inglesa me pierdo bastante con mi poco inglés.

Muchas gracias de antemano, un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problema

***Ejecutas el programa A y B en una misma ventana, por eso tienes que esperar que el programa A termine antes de poder ejecutar el programa B.***

#### Solución

Puedes solucionarlo modificando ligeramente tu código para especificar que quieres que el programa A y B se ejecuten de forma independiente. Esto lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
@ECHO OFF

CD C:\Users\usuario\Documents

ECHO LLAMADA A PROGRAMA A
START "Programa A" cmd /k "programaA.cmd > programaA.txt"

ECHO LLAMADA A PROGRAMA B
START "Programa B" cmd /k "programaB.cmd > programaB.txt"

PAUSE
EXIT
```

> `START "Título" cmd` inicia una nueva ventana cmd y le asigna un título, y `/k` envía un comando a esa ventana.

#### Ejemplo

**Colocar los tres scripts en el mismo directorio.**

*Script principal (que ejecuta los otros dos)*

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO LLAMADA A PROGRAMA A
START "Programa A" cmd /k "ProgramaA.cmd > ProgramaA.txt"

ECHO LLAMADA A PROGRAMA B
START "Programa B" cmd /k "ProgramaB.cmd > ProgramaB.txt"

PAUSE
EXIT
```

*Script ProgramaA*

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO "Hello World 1"
```

*Script ProgramaB*

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO "Hello World 2"
```

**Al ejecutar el script principal se crean dos archivos txt con el siguiente contenido:**

*ProgramaA.txt*

```
"Hello World 1"
```

*ProgramaB.txt*

```
"Hello World 2"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tur respuesta @Ariel, funciona correctamente pero para mi caso que se ejecuten las dos tareas simultáneamente me puede producir "timeouts" al tratarse de volcado de ficheros a través de red. He probado a poner en el primer `START` el comando `/WAIT` y, una vez finalizada la tarea, no continúa a la segunda hasta que no cierro la ventana cmd de la primera. ¿Cómo puedo ejecutarlas secuencialmente? Un saludo.

Comment: Puedes poner un `PAUSE` al inicio  de cada programa y luego de ejecutrarlos todos con mi explicación, hacerlos partir manualmente cuando sea el momento adecuado

Comment: También puedes buscar si el proceso del programa anterior ya ha terminado y en caso afirmativo ejecutar el código del siguiente programa. Pero todo esto es tema para una nueva pregunta.